# ERROR in Illegal State issue when giving angular build

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am developing an angular application. It is running without any errors when I run it normally using `ng serve`. But, when I run `ng build --prod`, it is giving following error.

```
ERROR in Illegal State: referring to a type without a variable {"filePath":"/Users/admin/Documents/projects/simply-science-web-ui/simply-science/node_modules/@angular/forms/forms.d.ts","name":"NgControlStatusGroup","members":[]}
```

I could not understand what is the issue. Please help me solve this.  Please let me know if any further information is needed.

**UPDATE:**

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
}
```

Other:

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.1.3
```

Thanks...

Comment: which version of angular you have used?

Comment: @Abhishek, I updated the question. Please check once.

Comment: This error is mostly occurred version problem try to downgrade your version with `8.0.0` or share your code on stackblitz.

Comment: @Abhishek, I tried downgrading the app to 8.0.0. But, it is not happening. Please let me know how to downgrade to that specific version.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found this error can be caused by components being registered in multiple modules, for example in `app.module` and `my_feature_module.module`.

**Temporarily** disabling `tsconfig.json -> fullTemplateTypeCheck` and re-running `ng build --prod` might show the related component registration errors.

Comment: Thanks bro ... This showing atlist what is error :)

Comment: @Sebastian Wegert, Thanks. It helped me find the exact issue.